# Inline style determines header height, causes padding above and below logo

Tags: html, css

This code: `<div id="site-header-wrapper" class=" " style="height: 100px;">`

Causes this logo to have padding: [image]

I can't seem to find the source of the height of my header, it seems to be determined by css and is displayed in the inspector as inline.

Website URL: https://geovision2.marketingsciences.nl/

Comment: why are you using height ? if you still want to increase height, just apply on `<img>`

Comment: I am not. It's from a WordPress template. That's why I added the WordPress tag. I'm trying to find its source to remove it.

Comment: than try `<style type="text/css">
 #site-header-wrapper {
  height: unset !important; 
 }
</style>` inside your file

Comment: Try `#site-header .header-main { display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; }` - Not sure why you need `display: table-cell`

Comment: Why not overwrite the padding in your custom stylesheet?

Comment: Both solutions don't seem to work for me. Because the inline style that determines the header height overwrites everything.

Comment: @Matt.S Because there is no padding. At least, on the photo you can see clearly that the logo has padding. But when you try to find its source you can't find anything. I think the problem is the wrapper of the header.

Comment: the height of logo is 91 and the div is 100

Comment: i inspected your website. it doesnt show any padding for me

Comment: @godfather the logo is automatically cropped by the theme, can't change the width/height because no div/id is given to the logo when the header shrinks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add height:auto; for site-logo as below, you will not see any padding. Try to avoid using inline styles because it's not good practice.

```
<div class="site-logo" style="width:164px;height: auto;">

</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. For some reason it has no effect in the inspector, nor in my css customizer. With or without !important. I don't do inline css, it's the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You could always target it in your CSS and give it `margin: 0 !important; padding: 0 !important;` . Its not the cleanest but thats the only thing that beats inline styles in the css hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I solved it by changing the header height according to the picture on every size change. Now it is responsive. Height: auto; didn't work for some reason because I think the css needed a specific size to replace the inline style that was determining the standard 100px.